# What is the difference between Qt Quick Styles and Qt Style Sheets?

Tags: qt, qml

For what I haver researched, both use QML, however, are the standard built in Qt Quick Styles just style sheets? Is Qt Quick an interface that is used to access the style sheets? If not, what are the differences? I don't seem to find much information comparing both on the internet, even though they both look pretty similar.

Comment: _both use QML_, where exactly have you found this information?

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same. By "Qt Quick Styles", I assume you mean styling Qt Quick Controls ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-styles.html))? That is a set of built-in customizable styles specifically for Qt Quick Controls (which is a library of ready-made controls including Buttons, Checkboxes, etc). You can specify the style you want by simply importing it:

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Material
```

But Qt Style Sheets has nothing to do with QML at all. It's used for Qt Widgets (the C++-only part of Qt), and it's more related to CSS style sheets. The reference docs are found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html). You can define styles in style sheets just like CSS, but with Qt named objects:

```
QPushButton::menu-indicator {
    image: url(myindicator.png);
    subcontrol-position: right center;
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    left: -2px;
}
```